# Strimzi Cluster operator not Able to start

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, strimzi

I'm trying to get a kafka cluster up through strimzi but the strimzi-cluster-operator keeps throwing following exception, if I try to do a kafka deployment, that triggers nothing:

**complete logs of strimzi-cluster-operator:**

```
Auto-detection of KUBERNETES_SERVICE_DNS_DOMAIN failed. The default value cluster.local will be used.
+ exec /usr/bin/tini -w -e 143 -- java -Dlog4j2.configurationFile=file:/opt/strimzi/custom-config/log4j2.properties -Dvertx.cacheDirBase=/tmp/vertx-cache -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom --illegal-access=deny -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:MinRAMPercentage=10 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=20 -classpath lib/io.strimzi.cluster-operator-0.31.1.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-codec-socks-4.1.77.Final.jar:lib/io.strimzi.operator-common-0.31.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-flowcontrol-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-model-config-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-model-machineconfig-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-handler-proxy-4.1.77.Final.jar:lib/io.strimzi.kafka-oauth-server-0.10.0.jar:lib/io.strimzi.crd-annotations-0.31.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-node-6.1.1.jar:lib/org.hdrhistogram.HdrHistogram-2.1.11.jar:lib/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.12.6.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-model-machine-6.1.1.jar:lib/com.squareup.okhttp3.logging-interceptor-3.12.12.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-admissionregistration-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-apps-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-scheduling-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-model-operatorhub-6.1.1.jar:lib/org.apache.zookeeper.zookeeper-jute-3.6.3.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.77.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-model-6.1.1.jar:lib/org.apache.zookeeper.zookeeper-3.6.3.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:lib/net.minidev.accessors-smart-2.4.7.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-handler-4.1.77.Final.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-model-clusterautoscaling-6.1.1.jar:lib/com.github.mifmif.generex-1.0.2.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-batch-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-extensions-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-coordination-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-client-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-codec-http-4.1.77.Final.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-model-tuned-6.1.1.jar:lib/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.3.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-rbac-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-model-operator-6.1.1.jar:lib/org.apache.kafka.kafka-clients-3.2.3.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-common-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-events-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-autoscaling-6.1.1.jar:lib/com.jayway.jsonpath.json-path-2.6.0.jar:lib/net.minidev.json-smart-2.4.7.jar:lib/io.strimzi.kafka-oauth-server-plain-0.10.0.jar:lib/org.yaml.snakeyaml-1.32.jar:lib/io.fabric8.zjsonpatch-0.3.0.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-codec-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-model-monitoring-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-metrics-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-storageclass-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-resolver-4.1.77.Final.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-networking-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.strimzi.kafka-oauth-common-0.10.0.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.77.Final.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-certificates-6.1.1.jar:lib/org.quartz-scheduler.quartz-2.3.2.jar:lib/io.prometheus.simpleclient_common-0.7.0.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-model-miscellaneous-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.77.Final.jar:lib/org.lz4.lz4-java-1.8.0.jar:lib/io.vertx.vertx-core-4.2.4.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-model-hive-6.1.1.jar:lib/com.squareup.okio.okio-1.15.0.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-policy-6.1.1.jar:lib/org.xerial.snappy.snappy-java-1.1.8.4.jar:lib/org.slf4j.slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-model-installer-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-client-api-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-model-storageversionmigrator-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-httpclient-okhttp-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.prometheus.simpleclient-0.7.0.jar:lib/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind-2.12.6.1.jar:lib/org.apache.yetus.audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-codec-4.1.77.Final.jar:lib/io.micrometer.micrometer-core-1.3.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-core-6.1.1.jar:lib/com.nimbusds.nimbus-jose-jwt-9.10.jar:lib/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core-2.12.6.jar:lib/com.squareup.okhttp3.okhttp-3.12.12.jar:lib/org.apache.logging.log4j.log4j-api-2.17.2.jar:lib/org.apache.logging.log4j.log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.2.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-model-console-6.1.1.jar:lib/com.github.stephenc.jcip.jcip-annotations-1.0-1.jar:lib/io.strimzi.kafka-oauth-client-0.10.0.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-client-api-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-buffer-4.1.77.Final.jar:lib/org.apache.logging.log4j.log4j-core-2.17.2.jar:lib/io.strimzi.certificate-manager-0.31.1.jar:lib/dk.brics.automaton.automaton-1.11-8.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-apiextensions-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-discovery-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-codec-http2-4.1.77.Final.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-model-whereabouts-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-gatewayapi-6.1.1.jar:lib/com.github.luben.zstd-jni-1.5.2-1.jar:lib/io.strimzi.api-0.31.1.jar:lib/io.strimzi.config-model-0.31.1.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.77.Final.jar:lib/org.latencyutils.LatencyUtils-2.0.3.jar:lib/io.vertx.vertx-micrometer-metrics-4.2.4.jar:lib/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations-2.12.6.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-client-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.micrometer.micrometer-registry-prometheus-1.3.1.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar io.strimzi.operator.cluster.Main
2022-10-20 15:32:06 INFO  Main:74 - ClusterOperator 0.31.1 is starting
2022-10-20 15:32:06 INFO  Util:313 - Using config:
        PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
        container: oci
        STRIMZI_DEFAULT_TOPIC_OPERATOR_IMAGE: quay.io/strimzi/operator:0.31.1
        JAVA_OPTS:  -Dlog4j2.configurationFile=file:/opt/strimzi/custom-config/log4j2.properties -Dvertx.cacheDirBase=/tmp/vertx-cache -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom  --illegal-access=deny -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:MinRAMPercentage=10 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=20
        STRIMZI_HOME: /opt/strimzi
        PWD: /opt/strimzi
        STRIMZI_LEADER_ELECTION_IDENTITY: strimzi-cluster-operator-54c4fcbb99-wf82k
        KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP: tcp://10.43.0.1:443
        JAVA_MAIN: io.strimzi.operator.cluster.Main
        STRIMZI_LEADER_ELECTION_ENABLED: true
        STRIMZI_VERSION: 0.31.1
        STRIMZI_DEFAULT_JMXTRANS_IMAGE: quay.io/strimzi/jmxtrans:0.31.1
        STRIMZI_NAMESPACE: kafka
        STRIMZI_DEFAULT_KANIKO_EXECUTOR_IMAGE: quay.io/strimzi/kaniko-executor:0.31.1
        TINI_SHA256_S390X: 931b70a182af879ca249ae9de87ef68423121b38d235c78997fafc680ceab32d
        STRIMZI_DEFAULT_MAVEN_BUILDER: quay.io/strimzi/maven-builder:0.31.1
        STRIMZI_FEATURE_GATES:
        TINI_SHA256_AMD64: 93dcc18adc78c65a028a84799ecf8ad40c936fdfc5f2a57b1acda5a8117fa82c
        STRIMZI_LEADER_ELECTION_LEASE_NAME: strimzi-cluster-operator
        KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS: 443
        SHLVL: 0
        STRIMZI_DEFAULT_KAFKA_BRIDGE_IMAGE: quay.io/strimzi/kafka-bridge:0.22.1
        KUBERNETES_PORT: tcp://10.43.0.1:443
        STRIMZI_KAFKA_MIRROR_MAKER_IMAGES: 3.1.0=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.0
3.1.1=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.1
3.1.2=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.2
3.2.0=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.0
3.2.1=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.1
3.2.3=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.3

        JAVA_HOME: /usr/lib/jvm/jre-11
        STRIMZI_FULL_RECONCILIATION_INTERVAL_MS: 120000
        KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST: 10.43.0.1
        JAVA_CLASSPATH: lib/io.strimzi.cluster-operator-0.31.1.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-codec-socks-4.1.77.Final.jar:lib/io.strimzi.operator-common-0.31.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-flowcontrol-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-model-config-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-model-machineconfig-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-handler-proxy-4.1.77.Final.jar:lib/io.strimzi.kafka-oauth-server-0.10.0.jar:lib/io.strimzi.crd-annotations-0.31.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-node-6.1.1.jar:lib/org.hdrhistogram.HdrHistogram-2.1.11.jar:lib/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.12.6.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-model-machine-6.1.1.jar:lib/com.squareup.okhttp3.logging-interceptor-3.12.12.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-admissionregistration-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-apps-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-scheduling-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-model-operatorhub-6.1.1.jar:lib/org.apache.zookeeper.zookeeper-jute-3.6.3.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.77.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-model-6.1.1.jar:lib/org.apache.zookeeper.zookeeper-3.6.3.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:lib/net.minidev.accessors-smart-2.4.7.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-handler-4.1.77.Final.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-model-clusterautoscaling-6.1.1.jar:lib/com.github.mifmif.generex-1.0.2.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-batch-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-extensions-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-coordination-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-client-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-codec-http-4.1.77.Final.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-model-tuned-6.1.1.jar:lib/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.3.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-rbac-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-model-operator-6.1.1.jar:lib/org.apache.kafka.kafka-clients-3.2.3.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-common-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-events-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-autoscaling-6.1.1.jar:lib/com.jayway.jsonpath.json-path-2.6.0.jar:lib/net.minidev.json-smart-2.4.7.jar:lib/io.strimzi.kafka-oauth-server-plain-0.10.0.jar:lib/org.yaml.snakeyaml-1.32.jar:lib/io.fabric8.zjsonpatch-0.3.0.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-codec-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-model-monitoring-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-metrics-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-storageclass-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-resolver-4.1.77.Final.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-networking-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.strimzi.kafka-oauth-common-0.10.0.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.77.Final.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-certificates-6.1.1.jar:lib/org.quartz-scheduler.quartz-2.3.2.jar:lib/io.prometheus.simpleclient_common-0.7.0.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-model-miscellaneous-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.77.Final.jar:lib/org.lz4.lz4-java-1.8.0.jar:lib/io.vertx.vertx-core-4.2.4.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-model-hive-6.1.1.jar:lib/com.squareup.okio.okio-1.15.0.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-policy-6.1.1.jar:lib/org.xerial.snappy.snappy-java-1.1.8.4.jar:lib/org.slf4j.slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-model-installer-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-client-api-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-model-storageversionmigrator-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-httpclient-okhttp-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.prometheus.simpleclient-0.7.0.jar:lib/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind-2.12.6.1.jar:lib/org.apache.yetus.audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-codec-4.1.77.Final.jar:lib/io.micrometer.micrometer-core-1.3.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-core-6.1.1.jar:lib/com.nimbusds.nimbus-jose-jwt-9.10.jar:lib/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core-2.12.6.jar:lib/com.squareup.okhttp3.okhttp-3.12.12.jar:lib/org.apache.logging.log4j.log4j-api-2.17.2.jar:lib/org.apache.logging.log4j.log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.2.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-model-console-6.1.1.jar:lib/com.github.stephenc.jcip.jcip-annotations-1.0-1.jar:lib/io.strimzi.kafka-oauth-client-0.10.0.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-client-api-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-buffer-4.1.77.Final.jar:lib/org.apache.logging.log4j.log4j-core-2.17.2.jar:lib/io.strimzi.certificate-manager-0.31.1.jar:lib/dk.brics.automaton.automaton-1.11-8.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-apiextensions-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-discovery-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-codec-http2-4.1.77.Final.jar:lib/io.fabric8.openshift-model-whereabouts-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-model-gatewayapi-6.1.1.jar:lib/com.github.luben.zstd-jni-1.5.2-1.jar:lib/io.strimzi.api-0.31.1.jar:lib/io.strimzi.config-model-0.31.1.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.77.Final.jar:lib/org.latencyutils.LatencyUtils-2.0.3.jar:lib/io.vertx.vertx-micrometer-metrics-4.2.4.jar:lib/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations-2.12.6.jar:lib/io.fabric8.kubernetes-client-6.1.1.jar:lib/io.micrometer.micrometer-registry-prometheus-1.3.1.jar:lib/io.netty.netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar
        STRIMZI_DEFAULT_CRUISE_CONTROL_IMAGE: quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.3
        TINI_VERSION: v0.19.0
        STRIMZI_OPERATION_TIMEOUT_MS: 300000
        KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR: 10.43.0.1
        STRIMZI_LEADER_ELECTION_LEASE_NAMESPACE: kafka
        STRIMZI_KAFKA_MIRROR_MAKER_2_IMAGES: 3.1.0=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.0
3.1.1=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.1
3.1.2=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.2
3.2.0=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.0
3.2.1=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.1
3.2.3=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.3

        KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO: tcp
        STRIMZI_DEFAULT_USER_OPERATOR_IMAGE: quay.io/strimzi/operator:0.31.1
        KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT: 443
        STRIMZI_DEFAULT_KAFKA_EXPORTER_IMAGE: quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.3
        TINI_SHA256_ARM64: 07952557df20bfd2a95f9bef198b445e006171969499a1d361bd9e6f8e5e0e81
        STRIMZI_DEFAULT_KAFKA_INIT_IMAGE: quay.io/strimzi/operator:0.31.1
        TINI_SHA256_PPC64LE: 3f658420974768e40810001a038c29d003728c5fe86da211cff5059e48cfdfde
        HOSTNAME: strimzi-cluster-operator-54c4fcbb99-wf82k
        STRIMZI_KAFKA_CONNECT_IMAGES: 3.1.0=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.0
3.1.1=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.1
3.1.2=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.2
3.2.0=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.0
3.2.1=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.1
3.2.3=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.3

        STRIMZI_KAFKA_IMAGES: 3.1.0=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.0
3.1.1=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.1
3.1.2=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.2
3.2.0=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.0
3.2.1=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.1
3.2.3=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.3

        KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT: 443
        STRIMZI_DEFAULT_TLS_SIDECAR_ENTITY_OPERATOR_IMAGE: quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.3
        STRIMZI_OPERATOR_NAME: strimzi-cluster-operator-54c4fcbb99-wf82k
        HOME: /home/strimzi
        MALLOC_ARENA_MAX: 2
        STRIMZI_OPERATOR_NAMESPACE: kafka

2022-10-20 15:32:07 INFO  Main:77 - Cluster Operator configuration is ClusterOperatorConfig(namespaces=[kafka],reconciliationIntervalMs=120000,operationTimeoutMs=300000,connectBuildTimeoutMs=300000,createClusterRoles=false,networkPolicyGeneration=true,versions=versions{3.1.0={proto: 3.1 msg: 3.1 kafka-image: quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.0 connect-image: quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.0 mirrormaker-image: quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.0 mirrormaker2-image: quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.0}, 3.1.1={proto: 3.1 msg: 3.1 kafka-image: quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.1 connect-image: quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.1 mirrormaker-image: quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.1 mirrormaker2-image: quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.1}, 3.1.2={proto: 3.1 msg: 3.1 kafka-image: quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.2 connect-image: quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.2 mirrormaker-image: quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.2 mirrormaker2-image: quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.2}, 3.2.0={proto: 3.2 msg: 3.2 kafka-image: quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.0 connect-image: quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.0 mirrormaker-image: quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.0 mirrormaker2-image: quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.0}, 3.2.1={proto: 3.2 msg: 3.2 kafka-image: quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.1 connect-image: quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.1 mirrormaker-image: quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.1 mirrormaker2-image: quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.1}, 3.2.3={proto: 3.2 msg: 3.2 kafka-image: quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.3 connect-image: quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.3 mirrormaker-image: quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.3 mirrormaker2-image: quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.3}},imagePullPolicy=null,imagePullSecrets=null,operatorNamespace=kafka,operatorNamespaceLabels=null,customResourceSelector=null,featureGates=FeatureGates(controlPlaneListener=true,UseStrimziPodSets=true,UseKRaft=false),zkAdminSessionTimeoutMs=10000,dnsCacheTtlSec=30,podSetReconciliationOnly=false,podSetControllerWorkQueueSize=1024,operatorName=strimzi-cluster-operator-54c4fcbb99-wf82k,podSecurityProviderClass=io.strimzi.plugin.security.profiles.impl.BaselinePodSecurityProvider,leaderElectionConfig=LeaderElectionConfig{leaseName='strimzi-cluster-operator', namespace='kafka', identity='strimzi-cluster-operator-54c4fcbb99-wf82k', leaseDuration=PT15S, renewDeadline=PT10S, retryPeriod=PT2S})
2022-10-20 15:32:08 INFO  Main:336 - Health and metrics server is ready on port 8080)
2022-10-20 15:32:08 INFO  Main:245 - Waiting to become a leader
2022-10-20 15:32:19 ERROR LeaderElector:156 - Exception occurred while acquiring lock 'LeaseLock: kafka - strimzi-cluster-operator (strimzi-cluster-operator-54c4fcbb99-wf82k)'
io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation: [get]  for kind: [Lease]  with name: [strimzi-cluster-operator]  in namespace: [kafka]  failed.
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:159) ~[io.fabric8.kubernetes-client-api-6.1.1.jar:?]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:177) ~[io.fabric8.kubernetes-client-6.1.1.jar:?]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:139) ~[io.fabric8.kubernetes-client-6.1.1.jar:?]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:88) ~[io.fabric8.kubernetes-client-6.1.1.jar:?]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.extended.leaderelection.resourcelock.LeaseLock.get(LeaseLock.java:44) ~[io.fabric8.kubernetes-client-api-6.1.1.jar:?]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.extended.leaderelection.LeaderElector.tryAcquireOrRenew(LeaderElector.java:188) ~[io.fabric8.kubernetes-client-api-6.1.1.jar:?]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.extended.leaderelection.LeaderElector.lambda$acquire$4(LeaderElector.java:151) ~[io.fabric8.kubernetes-client-api-6.1.1.jar:?]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.extended.leaderelection.LeaderElector.lambda$loop$8(LeaderElector.java:253) ~[io.fabric8.kubernetes-client-api-6.1.1.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1736) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255) ~[?:?]
```

**kubectl describe pod :**

```
Name:             strimzi-cluster-operator-54c4fcbb99-wf82k
Namespace:        kafka
Priority:         0
Service Account:  strimzi-cluster-operator
Node:             uat-v-kub-**/**.**.84.50
Start Time:       Thu, 20 Oct 2022 20:31:23 +0500
Labels:           name=strimzi-cluster-operator
                  pod-template-hash=54c4fcbb99
                  strimzi.io/kind=cluster-operator
Annotations:      cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 10.42.2.128/32
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 10.42.2.128/32
Status:           Running
IP:               10.42.2.128
IPs:
  IP:           10.42.2.128
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/strimzi-cluster-operator-54c4fcbb99
Containers:
  strimzi-cluster-operator:
    Container ID:  docker://06693a4dedc0e9ff7e7bb58253810ec2181e77b675606cc4407ad03f9b5936da
    Image:         quay.io/strimzi/operator:0.31.1
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://quay.io/strimzi/operator@sha256:6aa750dadca809148e098db9071d10a5a580c35afbbf01db42f8be9ca5efa94f
    Port:          8080/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Args:
      /opt/strimzi/bin/cluster_operator_run.sh
    State:          Running
      Started:      Thu, 20 Oct 2022 20:31:24 +0500
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     1
      memory:  384Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:      200m
      memory:   384Mi
    Liveness:   http-get http://:http/healthy delay=10s timeout=1s period=30s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:  http-get http://:http/ready delay=10s timeout=1s period=30s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      STRIMZI_NAMESPACE:                                  kafka (v1:metadata.namespace)
      STRIMZI_FULL_RECONCILIATION_INTERVAL_MS:            120000
      STRIMZI_OPERATION_TIMEOUT_MS:                       300000
      STRIMZI_DEFAULT_TLS_SIDECAR_ENTITY_OPERATOR_IMAGE:  quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.3
      STRIMZI_DEFAULT_KAFKA_EXPORTER_IMAGE:               quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.3
      STRIMZI_DEFAULT_CRUISE_CONTROL_IMAGE:               quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.3
      STRIMZI_KAFKA_IMAGES:                               3.1.0=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.0
                                                          3.1.1=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.1
                                                          3.1.2=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.2
                                                          3.2.0=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.0
                                                          3.2.1=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.1
                                                          3.2.3=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.3

      STRIMZI_KAFKA_CONNECT_IMAGES:                       3.1.0=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.0
                                                          3.1.1=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.1
                                                          3.1.2=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.2
                                                          3.2.0=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.0
                                                          3.2.1=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.1
                                                          3.2.3=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.3

      STRIMZI_KAFKA_MIRROR_MAKER_IMAGES:                  3.1.0=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.0
                                                          3.1.1=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.1
                                                          3.1.2=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.2
                                                          3.2.0=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.0
                                                          3.2.1=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.1
                                                          3.2.3=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.3

      STRIMZI_KAFKA_MIRROR_MAKER_2_IMAGES:                3.1.0=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.0
                                                          3.1.1=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.1
                                                          3.1.2=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.2
                                                          3.2.0=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.0
                                                          3.2.1=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.1
                                                          3.2.3=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.2.3

      STRIMZI_DEFAULT_TOPIC_OPERATOR_IMAGE:               quay.io/strimzi/operator:0.31.1
      STRIMZI_DEFAULT_USER_OPERATOR_IMAGE:                quay.io/strimzi/operator:0.31.1
      STRIMZI_DEFAULT_KAFKA_INIT_IMAGE:                   quay.io/strimzi/operator:0.31.1
      STRIMZI_DEFAULT_KAFKA_BRIDGE_IMAGE:                 quay.io/strimzi/kafka-bridge:0.22.1
      STRIMZI_DEFAULT_JMXTRANS_IMAGE:                     quay.io/strimzi/jmxtrans:0.31.1
      STRIMZI_DEFAULT_KANIKO_EXECUTOR_IMAGE:              quay.io/strimzi/kaniko-executor:0.31.1
      STRIMZI_DEFAULT_MAVEN_BUILDER:                      quay.io/strimzi/maven-builder:0.31.1
      STRIMZI_OPERATOR_NAMESPACE:                         kafka (v1:metadata.namespace)
      STRIMZI_FEATURE_GATES:
      STRIMZI_LEADER_ELECTION_ENABLED:                    true
      STRIMZI_LEADER_ELECTION_LEASE_NAME:                 strimzi-cluster-operator
      STRIMZI_LEADER_ELECTION_LEASE_NAMESPACE:            kafka (v1:metadata.namespace)
      STRIMZI_LEADER_ELECTION_IDENTITY:                   strimzi-cluster-operator-54c4fcbb99-wf82k (v1:metadata.name)
    Mounts:
      /opt/strimzi/custom-config/ from co-config-volume (rw)
      /tmp from strimzi-tmp (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from strimzi-cluster-operator-token-z764w (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  strimzi-tmp:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     Memory
    SizeLimit:  1Mi
  co-config-volume:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      strimzi-cluster-operator
    Optional:  false
  strimzi-cluster-operator-token-z764w:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  strimzi-cluster-operator-token-z764w
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  8m6s                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned kafka/strimzi-cluster-operator-54c4fcbb99-wf82k to uat-v-kub-c3
  Normal   Pulled     8m5s                   kubelet            Container image "quay.io/strimzi/operator:0.31.1" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    8m5s                   kubelet            Created container strimzi-cluster-operator
  Normal   Started    8m5s                   kubelet            Started container strimzi-cluster-operator
  Warning  Unhealthy  7m41s                  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.42.2.128:8080/ready: dial tcp 10.42.2.128:8080: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy  7m21s (x2 over 7m51s)  kubelet            Liveness probe failed: Get http://10.42.2.128:8080/healthy: dial tcp 10.42.2.128:8080: connect: connection refused
```

**kubectl get pod**

```
kubectl get pod -n kafka
NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
strimzi-cluster-operator-54c4fcbb99-wf82k   1/1     Running   0          46m
```

i did `kubectl create -f 'https://strimzi.io/install/latest?namespace=kafka' -n kafka` to install strimzi.
**kafka deployment file**
character limited exceeded in body so i've attached a screenshot of deployment file
[image]

Comment: It seems like there is an issue with the `lease`, which is the kube resource used by the cluster operator to elect a leader whenever you deploy more than one replica of the cluster operator pods. 
Please show us the result of this command `kubectl describe lease strimzi-cluster-operator -n the_same_ns_where_the_cluster_operator_is_deployed`

Comment: This looks like the RBAC files didn't installed properly. Can you share the output from the `kubectl create -f 'https://strimzi.io/install/latest?namespace=kafka' -n kafka` command? I checked it on my cluster and it seems to work fine and deploy properly.